# Good JS **Dropdown** Checkbox Node Tree?

Tags: jquery, treeview

I'm looking for a good dropdown node tree that has checkboxes. Similar to [ASP.NET ComboBox / TreeView in ComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/treeviewcombobox/defaultcs.aspx?product=combobox):

[image]

A similar jQuery component I've found is [DDCL dropdown-check-list](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/):

[image]

but it's a list and not a tree.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're looking for, but in any way, this isn't a "please help me find something" kind of site, it's a "I've tried to make something and got stuck! could you help me?" kind of site.

Comment: Actually, this is a perfectly fine question.

Comment: I find the most easy to use combotree from jQuery EasyUI
http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=
But there is only one limitation - it is free only for GPL projects.

Comment: More specific if you need -> http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=gray&dir=ltr&pitem=Multiple%20ComboTree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/), particularly the [checkbox](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox) demo.

Comment: I was wondering if there might already be a treeview in a dropdown menu though?  I guess it's best to just build it.  Thanks!

Comment: jsTree is customizable, to a degree. It might accomplish what you need. Take a look at the various demos to a taste of what it does.

Comment: Perhaps you could build a pseudo-pulldown menu, using animations to hide/show a pulldown container `div`, within which you pour your jsTree `div`.